# TimeoutException when using headless option in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, headless

I'm trying to get inner html form an element. but I'm getting timeout exception in headless mode. If i disable headless, it works. I need the element in headless mode too.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./driver/chromedriver", options=options)
browser.get("https://inspiring-lewin-33088d.netlify.app")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
      expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "zp"))
    )
    s = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    print(s)
finally:    
    browser.close()
```

I have tried other solutions like adding

```
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080") options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
```

But they do not work. Your help Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Updating chrome to v66 and chromedriver to v2.38 in combination with setting the following options:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); 
options.addArguments("-- disable-extensions"); 
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false); 
options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'"); 
options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*"); 
options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); 
options.addArguments("--headless");
```

Should Solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace `presence_of_element_located` with `visibility_of_element_located` to make sure the element is fully loaded. Then you should be safe to `get_attribute('innerHTML')`. In case you are not waiting for an element that will be visible ever (because its hidden), then apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45906728/11257746)